# Console.ReadLine() crash in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

Why does my game crash when I add Console.ReadLine() in program.cs right before the game using statement.

```
using System;

namespace MyGame
{
#if WINDOWS || XBOX
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
        using (Game1 game = new Game1())
        {
            game.Run();
        }
    }
}
#endif
}
```

I get an IO Exception was unhandled.  Not enough storage is available to process this command.

Comment: Probably because there is no console.

Comment: I don't think so, Console.WriteLine() still works, and will even display in the output box when debugging.

Comment: Never mind, you were right.  I turned on the console output on the xna games properties and everything works great.

Comment: And why exactly would you want to do this? Use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() to output to the debug trace listener. Console.ReadLine() makes no sense in the context of an XNA game.

Comment: @Liquid_Wotter: You should create an answer with what you found out and accept it when allowed to (24h). That, or propose this question for deletion.