# Difficulty regarding "IOException Unhandled"

Tags: c#, keyboard, user-input

I have been recently trying to learn C# after having two classes in C++, thus I understand the most basic concepts about how OOP works. As for my question, I've been trying to assign a user inputted string to a class's public string variable, in the main class, using Console.ReadLine( );

Unfortunately, I keep getting an error that states "the handle is invalid". Because I'm not that familiar with C#, I don't fully understand how to correct this, nor why it is happening.

Here are the portions of code where I:

write the code for a class;

```
public class AAA
{
    public string A1;
    public string A2;
}
```

Instantiate the class:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    AAA aaa;

// The next portions of code are found within this class.

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        aaa = new AAA( );

        base.Initialize();
    }
```

And in the update section, try to assign the keyboard input to the variables A1 and A2 from the AAA class:

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here

            Console.WriteLine("Enter your first name" + Environment.NewLine);
            aaa.A1 = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Enter your last name" + Environment.NewLine);
            aaa.A2 = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Your name is:" + Environment.NewLine + aaa.A1 + " " + aaa.A2);

            Console.Read( );

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

Now, The above might have turned out as rubbish. If so, I can try to stick the whole code in a reply (if that is easier for you all, in being able to review my code). But please let me know if there is any other information you might need regarding this.

Comment: Probably because there is no console for an XNA game. [This duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935642/console-readline-crash-in-xna) indicates that you need to turn on the console output in the XNA game properties. Why you want to use console input for a game is another whole question itself.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I think I mistook the term "console" for the window screen for the program while learning about keyboard inputs (as I didn't find the C++ equivalent to cin >>). So to rephrase the question, how do I input a string from the keyboard? All the other guides and q/a sites (including a book I got for XNA 4.0), only tell me how to check for the state of keys.

Comment: Ah, yes, I did. Sorry bout that, clicked enter by mistake -_-

Comment: I think the right answer is this: If you want to make a console program, just make a Console Application. If you want to make a video game, use XNA.

Comment: Oh wow. Well then, now I feel embarrassed. I'll give that a go. Thanks for the help by the way, though this turned out to be such a slight mistake on my part.

Comment: It's a somewhat obscure error, though, so I think the Internet as a whole is better off because of your struggles. I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're using XNA, as you're deriving from `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game`. I wouldn't be surprised if you're getting the "invalid handle" error when attemping to read from the console because *there is no console* for an XNA game.

The asker of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935642/console-readline-crash-in-xna) indicated that his solution was to "[turn] on the console output on the xna games properties".

It doesn't really make sense to be reading from the console for a video game, so I think the right answer is this: If you want to make a console program, just make a plain ol' C# Console Application. If you want to make a video game, use XNA.